# Local unit test for spark application throws out of memory exception

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, scalatest

I ran a spark local unit test application but it throws out of memory exception. The scala test starts with initialization of hbase minicluster and then initialization of spark session.

The version of spark is 2.1.0, here is part of exception log

```
2018-03-18 16:01:34 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
2018-03-18 16:01:34 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.10.208, 57931, None)
2018-03-18 16:01:34 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Registering block manager 192.168.10.208:57931 with 2.2 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.10.208, 57931, None)
2018-03-18 16:01:34 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.10.208, 57931, None)
2018-03-18 16:01:34 INFO  BlockManager:54 - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.10.208, 57931, None)
2018-03-18 16:01:36 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: SplitLogManager Timeout Monitor missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:01:36 ERROR MetricsSystem:70 - Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantiated
2018-03-18 16:01:38 INFO  MDMHbaseToTidbTaskTest:64 - close MDMHbaseToTidbTaskTest
2018-03-18 16:01:39 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: SplitLogManager Timeout Monitor missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:01:39 INFO  HBaseCommonTestingUtility:1095 - Shutting down minicluster
2018-03-18 16:01:39 INFO  ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:2259 - Closing master protocol: MasterService
2018-03-18 16:01:40 INFO  ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:1830 - Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x1623820ab0a0007

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor$Monitor@54b483bf"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JvmPauseMonitor"
2018-03-18 16:01:51 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: 192.168.10.208,57898,1521360088886-DoMetricsChore missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:01:52 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: SplitLogManager Timeout Monitor missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:01:52 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: CompactionChecker missed its start time

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-869429954_1 at /127.0.0.1:57900 [Cleaning up]"
2018-03-18 16:02:02 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: SplitLogManager Timeout Monitor missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:02:02 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: 192.168.10.208,57898,1521360088886-DoMetricsChore missed its start time
2018-03-18 16:02:03 INFO  CacheReplicationMonitor:179 - Rescanning after 37285 milliseconds
2018-03-18 16:02:02 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: 192.168.10.208,57901,1521360089611-MemstoreFlusherChore missed its start time

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor$Monitor@6e692fe"
2018-03-18 16:02:07 INFO  ScheduledChore:175 - Chore: SplitLogManager Timeout Monitor missed its start time

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

How to solve this problem. What config did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I found my specific reason. The permGen size is too small. I increase the permGen size to 1g. It runs well.